# »Schau ma mal« in Norddeutschland

Tags: dialect

Ich lerne in Bayern seit 2 Jahren Deutsch. Ich bin letze Woche nach Hamburg und Kiel gefahren. Ich habe dort die Redewendung »Schau ma mal« benutzt. Manche Leute haben mich zweimal aufgefordert das zu wiederholen.

Kann mir bitte jemand sagen, was die nordische Version der Redewendung »Schau ma mal» ist?

LG
Matt

Comment: Danke, dass du deine Frage auf Deutsch stellst! Du hattest zwar viele Fehler in deinem Posting, aber ich habe sie für dich korrigiert. Auch die Klassifizierung als »Standard-German« war falsch. In deiner Frage geht es um einen Dialekt-Ausdruck.

Comment: Der in Bayern und Österreich gängige Dialekt-Ausdruck »schau ma mal« würde im Standard-Deutsch »schauen wir einmal« lauten, ist aber nur im Dialekt gebräuchlich. Der Ausdruck kann je nach Kontext bedeuten: »Warten wir mal ab« oder »Sehen wir uns das mal an«. Leider habe ich aber keine Ahnung von norddeutschen Dialekten, und weis daher nicht, wie man das im Hamburger oder Kieler Dialekt sagt.

Comment: Spätestens seit Franz Beckenbauer sollte man das eigentlich nördlich der Mainlinie auch verstehen ;)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Dankeschön für die richtige Klassifizierung und deine Zeit um meine Frage zukorrigieren. Das ist sehr nett von dir. Deine Erklärung war echt klar. Jetzt verstehe ich mich wo ich diese Redewendung benutzen kann.

Comment: Das Verb "schauen" wird in Norddeutschland generell kaum gebraucht, stattdessen eher "sehen" oder "gucken".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's **mal sehen**, often shortened to *masehn*.

> Wirste heute noch fertich? — Masehn.
>
> Wirst du heute noch fertig? — Mal sehen.

*Are you going to finish (your work) today? — Let's see.*

> Da kannstamasehn, wiemandat richtich macht.
>
> Da kannst du mal sehen, wie man das richtig macht.

*There you see how to do it right.*

Comment: kannst**e**masehn?

Comment: Gibt es auch, ich kenn's aber ohne -e- oder mit -a-.

Comment: Stimmt, ohne -e- ist ganz im Norden sogar geläufiger als mit. Mit -a- hab ich es noch nie gehört.

Answer (score 4):

*»Schau ma mal«* wird gern zur Abwehr unliebsamer Fragen verwendet.

> »Sind Sie im September noch Trainer des FC Bayern?«
>
> »Schau ma mal.«

Man kennt zwar die Antwort, will sie aber nicht sagen.

Auf Hochdeutsch hieße das so viel wie: *»Das müssen Sie abwarten.«*

Comment: Oder: "Warten wir's ab" / "Warten Sie's ab." / "Wart's halt ab."

Answer (score 0):

Sag einfach "Kucken wir ma"

Comment: Die Antwort wurde durch einen Bot als minderwertig klassifiziert. Ein bisschen ausführlichere Antworten, gerne auch mit vollständiger Interpunktion,  werden hier besser angenommen.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/36860)

Comment: Keht das eikentlich, daß man "kuckt"? Manchmal hackts auch, statt daß es hakt.